# How precise/accurate Python OpenCV waitKey() for displaying an image for certain duration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I liked to display an image for certain duration, like 350ms, then display next one. To do that, I thought I can use `cv2.waitKey()` function from Python OpenCV library. Here is my code:

```
def display(filename, windows_height=935, windows_width=1826, wait_time=290):
img = cv2.imread(filename)
img_resize = cv2.resize(img, (windows_width, windows_height))
cv2.imshow('test', img_resize)
cv2.waitKey(wait_time)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_path1 = 'test_image_1.png'
    image_path2 = 'test_image_2.png'
    # image_list = [image_path1, image_path2]
    for x in range(10):
        for index, image in enumerate(image_list):
            start_time = time.time()
            display(image, windows_width=920, windows_height=540, wait_time=290)
            end_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            print('elapsed time of {} iteration of photo {} in millisecond: {}'.format(x, index, elapsed_time * 1000))
```

I also tried to calculate the elapsed time by using `time`. I assume, the `elapsed_time` in my code reflects how long I actually display that particular image.

My question are:

1. How accurate or precise the OpenCV waitKey() method? I know, `cv2.waitKey()` accepts argument in millisecond.However, if I type `cv2.waitKey(290)`, `elapsed_time` becomes 350ms.
2. Why `cv2.waitKey(350)` cause `elapsed_time` to be more than 350ms?
3. Any suggestion, how can my program be more precise regarding the timing?

Thank you very much

Aybars

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7): "Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time."

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you for your answer. It is clear to me now. If you share it as answer, I will accept it. Have a nice day!